# Combining two NSStrings and a number

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

Here is my code:

```
NSString *targetPath =@"/Users/miguelcosta/Desktop/Image.png";
```

In this NSString I want to do something like this:

```
NSString *targetPath =@"/Users/miguelcosta/Desktop/Image", RandomNumber + @"png";
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` exists exactly for this purpose

Comment: @sulthan: make an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your random number is an int, you can use the below

```
NSString* fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/miguelcosta/Desktop/Image%d.png", random];
```

Answer (score 1):

Formatting using `NSNumber` and image extension

```
NSNumber *randomNumber = @33;
NSString *extension = @"png";
NSString *targetPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/miguelcosta/Desktop/Image%@.%@", randomNumber, extension];
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer so other users can benefit from it.